# LINQ how to translate subquery in FROM clause

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nested, subquery

Newb to C#.Net / LINQ
I have to convert some dynamic stored procs to LINQ.  I'm new to LINQ, and looking for an example to follow.  I have something like the following:

```
sql1 VARCHAR2(32000)  := ' SELECT a,b,c FROM ( ';
from1 VARCHAR2(32000) := ' SELECT x,y,z FROM t1, t2,
                               (SELECT xx FROM aTable WHERE foo = 'bar' )
                            WHERE x=1
                              AND y=2';
```

Anyway, hope this gets the example across.
I was hoping to do something like:

```
var subSelect1 = (from val1 in aTable
                 where  val1.foo = "bar"
                 select new {
                     val1.foobar
                 }).AsEnumerable();

var mainSelect = (from <how do I use the subSelect1 as a virtual table here?>
```

Is this possible in LINQ?

The actual query is quite long and complex...having several subqueries in the FROM clause of the main select, and some of the subqueries in the FROM have themselves nested subqueries in -their- FROM clause.

Comment: Remove `.AsEnumerable()`, as that will cause the values to materialize when enumerated (rather than keeping it lazily executed). Then you simply write `subSelect1.Where(s => s.foobar == "test")`, etc.

Comment: @Rob I don't believe `AsEnumerable()` will enumerate the collection, but would like to read up on it if that is a potential side-effect.

Comment: @JonathonChase Nope, it won't cause them to be enumerated, but it will cause the values to be *materialized* when enumerated. For example, if you were to write `mainSelect = subSelect1.Take(5)` - this would load the entire table into memory, and then discard everything except the first 5 results, as opposed to generating SQL which only returns the first 5 results.

Comment: Because we're jumping from a lazy IQueryable Linq2SQL to IEnumerable Linq2Objects, right? At least, that makes sense to me. Thanks!

Comment: Can I chain the lambdas to reflect nested subqueries within a nested subquery in the top-level query (or its sub-queries)?

Comment: @frododot chaining is indeed what is required in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What may help is going through a couple sample linq queries and look at the results.  For example, the following code will create an IEnumerable of val1's.

```
var subSelect1 = (from val1 in aTable 
    where  val1.foo = "bar" 
);
```

Note the above is equivalent to the below.

```
var subSelect1 = (from val1 in aTable 
    where  val1.foo = "bar" 
    select val1 /* this select statement is implied in the above */
);
```

Adding the select new {val1.foobar} after the where clause creates an IEnumerable of an anonymous type, with one property named foobar.  This means that you'll only be able to join against the one property foobar.

```
var subSelect1 = (from val1 in aTable
         where  val1.foo == "bar"
         select new {val1.foobar}
    );

var mainSelect = (from f in subSelect1
         where f.foobar == "test")
```

By leaving out the select new, you'll have access to all the fields in val1.

```
var subSelect1 = (from val1 in aTable 
    where  val1.foo == "bar" 
);

var mainSelect = (from v in subSelect1
    where v.foobar == "test"
        and v.bar == "status"
)
```

Comment: I'd put the `select new` as I thought all LINQ statements will require this syntactically (won't compile without it).  Our system is unavailable at this moment, otherwise I would try and verify this.

Comment: The query without the select compiles and runs on my end. To make it a bit more intuitive, you could put select val1 instead, see edits above.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very clear regarding your exact `requirement`, but my understanding is you need a chained `Linq Query` such that the parent data can be filtered using the `Subquery` result. Also the Fluent syntax is a set of extension methods on  `IEnumerable<T>`, therefore a `DataTable` needs `AsEnumerable()` to be called so that operations can be done on `IEnumerable<DataRow>` and later on  `CopyToDataTable` in the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` can be called for re-conversion. Also since we are dealing with `DataRows`, therefore value access need `indexer`, like `dataRow["ColumnName"]` or `dataRow[ColumnIndex]`

// `dr` is the `DataRow` type (fetching all the Datarows, instead of specific Column like `foobar`)

> Creating Subselect1 `IEnumerable<DataRow>`

```
var subSelect1 = aTable.AsEnumerable()
                       .Where(dr => dr["foo"] == "bar")
```

> `var mainSelect = (from <how do I use the subSelect1 as a virtual table here?`

This shall be simple, depending on exactly what you need to do I assume, you need to match the `DataRows` that exist in `subSelect1`, then so something like:

```
var mainSelect = MainDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                              .Where(dr => subSelect1.Contains(dr))

var mainSelectDataTable = mainSelect.CopyToDataTable();
```

Idea remains, its very simple to create complex chained queries in Linq, provided you know exactly what you need, which is not very clear from the question